# Nuxt3 - can't start dev server

Tags: npm, nuxtjs3

Trying to setup a new Nuxt3 project lead to this error:

`ERROR  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'port')`

Following the docs:

- `npx nuxi init <project-name>`
- cd `<project-name>`
- `npm install`
- `npm run dev`

The full error message:

```
Nuxi 3.3.1                                                           
Nuxt 3.3.1 with Nitro 2.3.1                                           

 ERROR  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'port')          

  at Object.invoke (node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/dev.mjs:6777:78)
  at async _main (node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:49:20)
```

Since I have not written any code in the App I think it is my npm/nvm/node version or something.
Using

- node 18.15.0
- npm 9.5.0

Which version or update command do I need to run?
Can somebody point me towards the direction of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WORKAROUND**:
Adding `devServer: {}` to `nuxt.config.ts`

---

`nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    devServer: {}
})
```

---

️ Further reading here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19164